# Magento 2 Module not loads

Tags: magento2, module

even after enabling the module using command-line
the modules content are not loading,

in app/etc/config.php it sets the value as one    'Turtle_VM' => 1,

but in local system and staging the module is working fine

i run the following command to enable the module:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Turtle_VM
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Once Again In this Order. make sure there are no any error on setup:upgrade and static-content:deploy.

```
chmod -R 777 var pub/static/
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
rm -rf generated/*
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento module:enable Turtle_VM
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:clean
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:flush
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento indexer:reindex
chmod -R 777 var pub/static/
```

Comment: is the procedure i follow is wrong?

Comment: is both cache:flush and cache:clean is needed

Comment: Yes. It needed.

Comment: i don't face any errors , everything was completed successfully

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or windows?

Comment: centos 7 version

Comment: I think after insert module files you need to run "sudo chmod -R 777 ./" to give permission for magento root.

Comment: Try to check module status with command first:php bin/magento module:status,is it showing as enabled?

Comment: Also remove files inside generated folder and do compile

Comment: module:status always shows as enabled

Answer (score 0):

try to run these commands from CLI.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```